# How do I make a list of documents in a directory whose names meet a name search criteria

Tags: python, operating-system

Here is the code that gives me the search results that I am looking for printed in the console (there happen to be 14).

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/ (...) /Downloads/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith(" (...) "):
            print(os.path.join(root,file))
```

However I need to have this result as a list, I have tried to do this in the following way:

```
download = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/(...)/Downloads/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith("(...)"):
            download.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

However, when I print this list, it returns fourteen iterations of lists, the first iteration with only one element and the last with all fourteen, increasing by one each time. I assume this has something to do with the way that the append attribute works.

Comment: What you claim is happening doesn't seem possible. If the first snippet only prints 14 file paths, the second should only append 14 of them to the list.

Comment: "_I assume this has something to do with the way that the append attribute works._" - Maybe it has more to do with the placement of the `print` statement?

Comment: Timus has it, I put the print statement at the same indentation as the 'download.append...' rookie error because I am a rookie.